# Read txt line by line and query AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a text file containing samids:

```
XXXXXXX
YYYYYYY
ZZZZZZZ
```

For each one I need to read it quering AD with this:

```
dsquery user forestroot -samid XXXXXXX | dsget user -email
```

and write the response into another file. Please help me :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Get-ADUser` from the `ActiveDirectory` PowerShell module instead of the ds tools:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' |
  Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'DC=example,DC=org' -Property mail |
  select -Expand mail | Out-File 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```

Where `DC=example,DC=org` is the distinguished name (DN) of your forest root domain.

For programmatically determining the DN of the forest root domain you could use this:

```
([ADSI]"LDAP://RootDSE").RootDomainNamingContext
```

Comment: Cool, this was exactly what I need, sorry for duplicate post, I thought it was necesary to split the steps. But it only works with current domain users, I'd need to search the whole domain. @Ansgar Wiechers

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to solve it this way proposed on the other post:

```
$a = Get-Content .\input.txt 
for ($i=0 ; $i -lt $a.Length; $i++){
 dsquery user forestroot -samid $a[$i] | dsget user -email | Select-String '@' | select -Expand Line >> output.txt
}
```

Thank you