# Regex to clear out a response

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm getting this output

```
email              
  xxx@consoso.com  
dsget succeeded
email              
  yyy@contoso.uk 
dsget succeeded
```

to my command:

`dsquery user forestroot -samid %%i | dsget user -email`

but I'm only interested in email addresses. Does anybody know the proper regex to clear everything out but the email addresses? It would be great that I could pipe it after my command like this:

`dsquery user forestroot -samid %%i | dsget user -email | whateverRegex`

To get only:

```
 xxx@consoso.com 
 yyy@contoso.uk
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read txt line by line and query AD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450817/read-txt-line-by-line-and-query-ad). Please avoid posting multiple questions with only slightly different objectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the `@` in the mail addresses, like this:

```
dsquery user forestroot -samid %%i | dsget user -email | Select-String '@' |
  select -Expand Line
```

However, it'd be a lot simpler to just use the cmdlets from the `ActiveDirectory` module if you're using PowerShell anyway:

```
Get-ADUser -Id $id -Property mail | select -Expand mail
```

Comment: Thank you! the first code already works, but I'd rather use the second one, how could I start the query in the forest root instead of the current subdomain? I tried `Get-ADUser -id $id -SearchScope Base -Property mail | select -Expand mail` but it doesnt work.

Comment: @srbob See my answer to your other question.

Comment: It seems it's needing something more... Get-ADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'SearchBase'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:36
+ Get-ADUser -Id XXXX -SearchBase DC=contoso,DC=local
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: @srbob Please disregard this answer. Or rather, delete this whole question and stick with your other question. My answer there is working.

Answer (score 0):

another variant much faster:

```
PS D:\> $s = @'
>> email
>>   xxx@consoso.com
>> dsget succeeded
>> email
>>   yyy@contoso.uk
>> dsget succeeded
>> '@.split("`r`n")
>>

PS D:\> [regex]::Matches($s,'(?<=email *)[^\s]+') | select value

Value
-----
xxx@consoso.com
yyy@contoso.uk
```